# Point-free JavaScript: write a function runner

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, programming-puzzle

In this [programming-puzzle](/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle), your goal is to write the following function in JavaScript, using (essentially) [point-free (*tacit*) programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming):

```
(f) => void(f())
```

Your submission should be an expression which returns a function which behaves like the above (taking a function as an argument and calling it, and returning `undefined`), without writing a function definition (defined objectively below). You must instead achieve the behavior by combining existing functions (e.g., `Function.prototype.apply`).

Any JS is valid, with the exception of the following:

- Function definitions using the `function` keyword, arrow function syntax, or object/class method syntax
- Function definitions using `new Function` or the `Function` constructor
- Evaluation of code using `eval` (directly or indirectly)
- Relying on browser-only functionality or import/filesystem/OS/FFI libraries in Node.js

If this is not possible, a proof of its impossibility is also a valid submission. Solutions will be scored by byte count; smallest solution is best.

Comment: May a submission use a function that has no body like `()=>{}` or `function*(){}`?

Comment: @noodleman No, but most things you could do with that, you could probably do with an existing function in the language (e.g., `[].find` like emanresu uses)

Comment: Must the submission pass no argument to the function?

Comment: @noodleman Yes, but if you have an interesting solution that does pass an argument, maybe post it in an answer alongside a more valid (if ungolfy) variant

Comment: You did not restrict getter/setter syntax, on purpose?

Comment: Why the `void` operator, btw? This makes it quite hard…

Comment: Is "*taking a function as an argument and calling it, and returning undefined*" the only requirement for equivalency to your function? Does the solution need to have the same arity (`1`)? Does it need to call `f` with no arguments (and does `undefined` count)? Does it need to call `f` with no `this` value? Does it need to call `f` synchronously? Does the solution need to have no `.name`? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Bergi The solution's `.name` and `.length` don't matter, nor does the `this` value `f` sees. As for the "returning `undefined`" part, it just happened to be part of the problem I was idly attempting while bored at work; it's not for any clever reason.

Comment: @Bergi `get`/`set` was an oversight on my part, but I'll leave it as something allowed, just since it's very in the spirit of this site

Comment: AFAICT, `(f) => void(f())` is not possible  (without using the loophole) but `([f]) => void(f())` is. It is so frustratingly close to being possible damnit.

Comment: @TwiNight How would you do that?

Comment: @Bergi Haven't taken the time to fully golf it down but [like this](https://tio.run/##bY/BCsIwDIbvPkVua2D2IB4E8ejRJxg71LpuldKWthsT8dlryg5j4iXw5c//J3mKSUQZtE/76ZSlszFBGC1cctNy5cJVyIHftX2w5iY8l8KYBQsJ781rxa1YCBHbGtYkzGq0MmlnQTHOuQh9RHhD2etMx43rWVWMFZ5/mmmuakiDjqRQGrDlVkoAp@BvEDXJQ5UsHwhdGoOF44Fgt5kjheboa9aoFjF/AQ)

Answer (score 12):

### Why I believe this is impossible (as stated)

There aren't very many JS builtins that call a function, and even fewer that call one with arbitrary arguments. The ones that I've found are the string methods `replace` and `replaceAll`, the array methods `every`, `filter`, `find`, `findIndex`, `findLast`, `findLastIndex`, `flatMap`, `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `reduceRight`, and `some`; the the function methods `apply` and `call`; the global functions `Reflect.apply`, `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, the `Promise` constructor and (browser only) `requestAnimationFrame` and `addEventListener`, and also some weird stuff like `RegExp[@@replace]`.

All the array methods are useless, as they all call functions with the signature `f(item, index, array)`.

There are a few that call the function but can't return undefined. `String#replace` (along with `String#replaceAll` and `RegExp[@@replace]`) almost work with `''.replace.bind('', /(?:)/g)`, but returns the function's result stringified. `setTimeout` ignores the function's return value, but returns a uid for that particular call (ditto with `setInterval`).

Likewise, the function methods `apply` and `call` return the return value of whatever function they're called with. `Reflect.construct` can be used to trigger the `Promise` constructor, but requires the arguments passed to the constructor function to be placed in an array.

Event listeners are somewhat promising, taking a function and returning undefined, but there's no way to create an object which has an event occur on it every time the function is called. `window.addEventListener.bind(window, 'click')` (browser only) does work to call a function every time a click is called though.

As calling the expression with the input function has to be the last operation performed on the expression, I don't think there's any way to transform whatever non-`undefined` value is returned into `undefined`. And since there's no built-in function capable of both instantly calling the function a single time without arguments and returning `undefined`, I don't think this challenge is possible.

---

#### (old answer, calls with nonempty args) 17 bytes

```javascript
[].find.bind([,])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcqxDYAgEEDRVa6DS5ANdBFDgYCKEM7oqWyPtja/eX@ztz3dEXfuCvnQEvTQRqPnWLyevshRGWyOykk56EyLFHTxfrFQkGSFfoAfOptz8PBEXr@jImJ7AQ)

<s>I'm pretty sure this is optimal</s> -3 bytes thanks to Neil.

Calls the function on an array `[,]`, passing `undefined` to it. If the function's return value is truthy, the `undefined` is returned; if it's falsy the `find` call fails and returns `undefined`.

Comment: `[,]` saves 3 bytes.

Comment: @Neil I'm surprised that works, it feels like it should be either 0 calls or 2 calls. Sparse arrays are weird. Thanks!

Comment: Fortunately `find` loops from `0` to the length (the object you bind it to doesn't even need to be an array as long as it has an integer length).

Comment: This [does call `f` with 3 arguments](https://tio.run/##VcqxDYAgEADAVb4DEvwNdBFCgYCKEJ4I6vhoY2Fz1e3mMtUeobQhk/M9wghdaVxCdji/cCW16JZypeQx0coZna2cjUmInCOiOdYqYJzgl6xJyTu4Q9ve@TUh@gM) though

Comment: @Bergi I forgot `find` works like that, and you're right that calling it with undefined isn't quite the same as calling it with no arguments. I guess we'll wait for OP's clarifications.

Comment: @emanresuA He actually [did clarify already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267409/point-free-javascript-write-a-function-runner/267410?noredirect=1#comment582344_267409) in a response to noodleman

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>74</s> 65 bytes

```javascript
[].forEach.bind([{[Symbol.split]:(c=Map.call).bind(c)}],''.split)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bU-xCsIwEN39ituSQM0gDqJ0cHB0ciwd2rRpCzEpSQpK6Ze4VNDJL_JvvJIuissd9-69d-9uD22KcnwJo50H22mIn52Xy817n6RcGnvIRM3zRhc06ZPT9ZwbxV2rGp9uqYiPWctFphQLFMGGNCIkENhsdJedFr4xGiTlnGe2cgx6mC4aVXJlKkomD8J2P6C_kAh83TjcYBSgISU6gJHw1whB1GBFyQC29J3VsF7hsPji4QZ5-C-VbA46jqF_AA)

Comment: This is absolutely awesome! Calling `String.prototype.split` with a function as the receiver, because that'll be forwarded to the `[Symbol.split]` method, is just crazy…

Comment: -9: you don't actually need a `length` on the splittee for anything ([demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bU-xCsIwEN39ituSQM0gDqJ0cHB0ciwd2rRpCzEpSQpK6Ze4VNDJL_JvvJIuissd9-69d-9uD22KcnwJo50H22mIn52Xy817n6RcGnvIRM3zRhc06ZPT9ZwbxV2rGp9uqYiPWctFphQLFMGGNCIkENhsdJedFr4xGiTlnGe2cgx6mC4aVXJlKkomD8J2P6C_kAh83TjcYBSgISU6gJHw1whB1GBFyQC29J3VsF7hsPji4QZ5-C-VbA46jqF_AA))

Comment: @Bergi Oh true. I added that because I was planning to use `Function#apply` to remove any additional args but did not check again whether that is necessary after I finished.

Comment: So, calling `run(f)` runs `forEach` on that inner object, passing it as the argument to `String.prototype.split`, with `f` as the `thisArg`. `split` then calls the `Symbol.split` function of that inner object, passing `f` and `0` as arguments. That's equivalent to calling `Function.prototype.call.call(f, 0)` which is equivalent to calling `f.call(0)`, which is equivalent to setting `f` as a property on `Number.prototype` and invoking that on `0`.

Comment: @Neil See also [my explanation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68481) I had tried to edit into the answer

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a loophole in the function definition restriction, but you can still define a setter:

```
({set s(f){f()}}).__lookupSetter__('s')
```

[`__lookupSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupSetter__) is non-standard and deprecated, but shorter than

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor({set s(f){f()}},'s').set
```